# Saved string in CoreData returns <null> and the string. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Hi i am saving values coming from a database in a MultableArray and then in CoreData:

```
 NSMultableArray *mutary = [[NSMultableArray alloc] init];
      NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    for(int n=0; n<[AttributeArray count]; n++)
    {

    [mutary addObject:[[AttributeArray objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"AttributName"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", mutary);
}
attributeString = [mutary componentsJoinedByString:@","];

 raume = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Raum" inManagedObjectContext:context];

raume.raumattribut = attributeString;

 if (![context save:&error]) {
 NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
 abort();
```

}

NSLog output for the MultableArray is:

```
    2012-06-20 17:21:00.047 book-app[31984:15803] (
    A7OVERHEAD,
    Beamer
)
```

So far its working correct. The two expected values from the database are now in the Array.
Now i am fetching these attributes from CoreData:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Raum" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *events = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

for (Raum *att in events)
    {
     stringAttribute = [[events valueForKey:@"raumattribut"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
     NSLog(@"ATTRIBUTE: %@", stringAttribute);
    }
}
```

So far so good. But if i look now on my NSLog output:

```
2012-06-20 17:21:00.055 book-app[31984:15803] ATTRIBUTE: <null>,A7OVERHEAD,Beamer
```

CoreData is returning  and then the two values. Where is that  coming from?

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After some investigating and clarifying (see comments), here is my answer:
Calling valueForKey on an NSArray returns an array where each element is created by calling valueForKey on each member of the original array. This means your output indicates that you have 3 total objects returned by your fetch request, and the first one does not have it's raumattribut attribute set.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:
You are calling valueForKey on an instance of NSArray (the query results). Perhaps you need to <del>get objectAtIndex:0</del> first use the variable you are iterating the values on? valueForKey is likely returning nil.

```
stringAttribute = [[att valueForKey:@"raumattribut"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

or similar.

EDIT:
At first I missed the for loop in the second part, I have edited the above code sample to use the attr, which

Comment: if i do it like that it returns only (null). Is there another solution?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Though I'm not sure what type the raumattribut property is, and if componentsJoinedByString is appropriate there.

Comment: this doesnt work. I get and Error: -[NSCFString componentsJoinedByString] unrecognized selector.. "raumattribute" is a NSString and why do you call [att valueForKey:@"raumattribut"] instead of [events valueForKey:@"raumattribut"]

Comment: events is an NSArray of NSManagedObjects, and therefore should return nil to any valueForKey sent to it. I suspected that raumattribute was not an array, and the componentsJoinedByString wouldn't work. Try just logging NSLog(@"%@", att) inside your loop. That should show you all the values with their keys in the NSManagedObject's data.

Comment: ok so but i have done this  stringAttribute = [[events valueForKey:@"raumattribut"] componentsJoinedByString:@","]; and the output from my NSLog is ATTRIBUTE: <null>,A7OVERHEAD,Beamer. So its not null, only the first value which is returned is <null>.

Comment: Okay, I check the documentation, and I learned that NSArray does respond to valueForKey, by returning an array of elements created by calling valueForKey on each of it's members. Now it seems obvious. You have 3 total objects which are being selected by your fetch request, and the first one has nothing set for the raumattribut key.

Comment: Yes but the strange thing is, how can there be 3 values. Look at my Output from my Array. I save the Array with two Value A7OVERHEAD and Beamer in CoreData.So i dont know where the third Value is coming from. This is confusing me. My Database is also returning also 2 Values.

Comment: Have you tried this outside of the for loop (which is not necessary)? And prior to the for loop, what is the value of [events count]?

Comment: i found the solution -.-. for (Raum *att in events){
    
        stringAttribute = att.raumattribut;
    

    } Anyway. Thanks for your help